# How to select only date part from SQL Server CE datetime column?

Tags: c#, select, sql-server-ce

I am using SQL Server CE database and C# language. I have a table with a `datetime` type column. I want to use a SELECT statement like

```
 SELECT * FROM Data WHERE Date = @Date
```

But I need only date part of the `datetime` value. So I can add parameter like

```
 SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", date.Date);
```

My problem is with `SELECT` statement I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of that you can use DateDIFF

```
SELECT * FROM Data WHERE DATEDIFF(day, Date, @Date)=0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Data WHERE DAY(Date) = DAY(@Date)
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!